# calculating the number of rows and colomns in an A4 page when Cell size is X by Y cm

Tags: vba, xls

hi all I have been looking all night and can't find anything that will fix my problem

I define a cell (A:3) as len=53mm Hgt=33mm and now I want to resize all the cells (from A:3 to ColLast:RowLast ) that fits into a pre defined area ie A4 page where Awidth=210 and Bhight=310 has been specified

also why when I print the cell using the following code

```
Sub SetColumnWidthMM(ColNo As Long, mmWidth As Double)
' changes the column width to mmWidth
Dim w As Single
    If ColNo < 1 Or ColNo > 255 Then Exit Sub
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    w = Application.CentimetersToPoints(mmWidth / 10)
    While Columns(ColNo + 1).Left - Columns(ColNo).Left - 0.1 > w
        Columns(ColNo).ColumnWidth = Columns(ColNo).ColumnWidth - 0.1
    Wend
    While Columns(ColNo + 1).Left - Columns(ColNo).Left + 0.1 < w
        Columns(ColNo).ColumnWidth = Columns(ColNo).ColumnWidth + 0.1
    Wend
    End Sub
```

The printed cell changes size depending on the type of printer I use... ??

Comment: I have been working on this and think I have almost got a working version If someone can tell me how to attach a 108Kb XLS file I'll would like to get some C/C on it

Answer (score 0):

Notice that different printers have different margins. So you must expect different layouts for same content in different printers.

Always take a look at `PageSetup.*Margin`.

Preferably, do not change your columns width, change page setup scaling.

By the way, what are you trying to achieve with your code?

Comment: I am a pen turner and I wrap custom designs around brass tube - So the size of the cell needs to be exact..  and to get the most out of an expensive sheet of silver I want to make sure before printing I get a full set out rather than just missing out cause of margines etc..

Comment: If you need exact fittings, why are you changing cells widths?

Comment: because the silver will wrap around the outside diameter I need to know the circumference as well as the length from the tip to the cap

Answer (score 0):

Self explanatory, I hope:

```
With Worksheets("sheetname").PageSetup
    .PaperSize = xlPaperA4 'Just to ensure we are using A4
    FullPageWidth_Points = Application.CentimetersToPoints(21#)
    AvailablePageWidth_Points = FullPageWidth_Points - .LeftMargin - .RightMargin
    AvailablePageWidth_Centimeters = AvailablePageWidth_Points /  Application.CentimetersToPoints(1#)
    MaxNumberOfCells = Int(AvailablePageWidth_Points - CellsWidth_Points)
End With
```

Comment: thanks for the code unfortunately I don't always have a full A4 sheet to work from

Comment: Ok, but this answers your question, isn't it?

Comment: I apologise... I think the title question may lead everyone to believe that it was only against A4 sheet, - and if so this code is exactly what I would need,  however it was meant to be an example, you will note it was originally stated as " that fits into a pre defined area ie A4 page where Awidth=210 and Bhight=310 has been specified" - If someone can show me how to upload a file I can show you my progress so far...